Seeking confirmation and detailed contextualization of that the founding fathers of the US opposed direct democracy
I recently read a number of quotes from people like James Madison, Alexander Hamilton, and Thomas Jefferson which all espoused the view that direct democracy was basically historically proven to be a failed form of governance.
I was never aware that the philosophical view of many of the architects of the US Constitution and other essentials laws was more or less meant to rule out the possibility of direct democracy, and was in a way not particularly favorably disposed towards hardcore libertarianism, but instead was in a very medial position between excessive freedom and monarchy.
For example, Alexander Hamilton is quoted saying, “We are now forming a republican government. Real liberty is neither found in despotism or the extremes of democracy, but in moderate governments.”
I was looking for further confirmation and some developed analysis about this claim.

Keep in mind that the way they used "democracy" back then was in the classical sense which was used by several philosophers as "rule by the mob" (what we would call a referendum) as opposed to the wise governance of the educated oligarch class that granted them patronage.

Read Pauline Maier

Does this question (and/or the answers to it) answer your question? Did the founding fathers of the USA really make a distinction between a Republic and a Democracy (and despised the latter)
